# Database with same name created in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I found that database with a same that already exists can be created, thus databases with the same names causes problems when I need to specify which databases I want to use.

Here is how it happens:

1. I already have a database, with name "test1",which only stores collections with documents.
2. Then, I use it to store files using GridFS so it contains binary files.(Actually, I think this could be the cause, but I have no idea why)
3. And now problem happens. When I try to access "test1" using command like `use test1`. An empty database with the same name "test1" will be created.

Like what `show dbs` demonstrates:

```
test1   empty
test1   0.0625GB
```

I am using mongodb 2.0.5

Any hint on why this happens, since common sense will show that db with the same name cannot coexist? And any solution?

Comment: what files are in your /data/db directory?

Comment: you may have some hidden Unicode character, which makes them look same for you, but not MongoDB?