# Why does getDatabaseNames() return a List and getCollectionNames() return a set in mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-java

In the following program `getDatabaseNames()` returns a list of values and `getCollectionNames()` returns a set of values. Why don't both return a `Set`?

Does this mean that we can create databases having the same name?

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class Collections2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClient client=null;
    try {
        client=new MongoClient();

        //Lists all the database names 
        System.out.println("List of databases ");
        List<String> DBset=client.getDatabaseNames();
        for(String string:DBset){
                System.out.println(string);
        }

        //list all the collection names in school DB
        DB db=client.getDB("school");
        System.out.println("List of collections in school DB");
        Set<String> set=db.getCollectionNames();
        for (String string:set) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

However strange this might sound, but yes!

This is not particular to Java. As [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908911/database-with-same-name-created-in-mongodb) states you can replicate this behaviour with the command line tool `mongo` too.

Quote from the question:

> Here is how it happens:
>
> 1. I already have a database, with name "test1",which only stores collections with documents.
> 2. Then, I use it to store files using GridFS so it contains binary files.(Actually, I think this could be the cause, but I have no idea why)
> 3. And now problem happens. When I try to access "test1" using command like use test1. An empty database with the same name "test1" will be created.
>
> Like what show dbs demonstrates:
>
> ```
> test1   empty
> test1   0.0625GB
> ```

As for how to deal with this, I'm not sure, because the Java driver has only this method for obtaining DBs (as of current stable, 2.10.1):

- [MongoClient.getDB(String name)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.10.1/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDB%28java.lang.String%29)

The other function, getUsedDatabases(), which would return DB instances returns only the DB objects that have been used by this instance of the MongoDB driver in this run.

This would mean, that while in the same runtime, you *could*  make use of this "feature" (?), and deal with both DBs of the same name, but that would make an ugly situation to clean up if something goes awry, and the JVM is shut down before cleaning up the mess... (Theoretically, as I can't confirm this right now... I will report back my findings when I'm near my development Mongo instance.)